# how to exit activities screen?

Tags: gnome

Somehow I've activated "Activites" screen which completely empty. How can I exit it?
I've tried Esc, Alt-F4, Ctrl-Alt-Del, Alt-Tab, clicking mouse buttons but this doesn't help.

[image: screen]

Comment: Could you please [edit] and explain what you tried? That way, we won't be giving you the obvious answers like "hit Esc" or "click somewhere". I assume you've already tried these and they didn't help, but we need to know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Press: <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> 

Then login and restart your `gdm`, `kdm` , or so on. It's related to your Desktop Environment.